# AWS S3 NoSuchKey when trying to open subfolder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I added subfolder (for example mysubfolder) to my site (for example https://www.example.com), and when I open this link (https://www.example.com/mysubfolder) on browser I get error:

> 404 Not Found
>
> Code: NoSuchKey
>
> Message: The specified key does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is probably to the wrong/misspelled path for your S3 static site. Make sure that `mysubfolder` exists in your bucket root path.

Comment: The subfolder exist, I currently have 3 subfolders, and getting same error for all 3.

Comment: are you able to access the root properly?

Comment: I was missing the file at the end of the folder name for example https://www.example.com/mysubfolder/index.htm